# ¿Como validar datos de un datatable en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables, webforms

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo un archivo excel que paso a un DataTable con 9 columnas(3 columnas de porcentaje, 1 columna de texto y 5 columnas con formato de pesos) todas de valor float menos la de texto que es string y donde algunas columnas puede que no este llena de valores es decir puede tener campos vacios.

Lo que requiero es poder validar que los datos sean del tipo de dato correcto al que pertenecen antes de poder enviarlos a la base de datos.

Aquí coloco mi código espero puedan ayudarme.

```
 foreach (DataRow validacion in datos_Actualizar.Rows)
        {
            float total_aPagar;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validacion[4].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    var operacion = float.Parse(validacion[4].ToString());

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    lblMensaje.Text = "El archivo excel contiene datos incorrectos";
                }


            }


        }
```

El problema es que no me muestra el mensaje de error.

Comment: como estas devolviendo el error hacia el cliente, agrega esa parte del codgio.

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate mi mensaje de error trato de enviarlo en la etiqueta lblMensaje. Ya que yo tengo mi DataTable y solo recorro mi tabla pero me he dado cuenta que como no todos los campos estan llenos el mensaje no se muestra.

Comment: Y este código, ¿cuándo lo ejecutas? ¿De manera asíncrona desde un evento javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar podrias usar el `TryParse()` asi no trabajas ante la exception

```
bool result = true;

foreach (DataRow validacion in datos_Actualizar.Rows)
{
    float total_aPagar = 0;

    if(!float.TrayParse(validacion[4].ToString(), out total_aPagar))
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(!result)
{
    lblMensaje.Text = "El archivo excel contiene datos incorrectos";
}
```

la idea es mostrar el mensaje al final cuando terminaste de evaluar las rows

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini  gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió mucho y esta corriendo perfectamente.